# Secure GoDaddy site with Azure SSL Certificate

Tags: azure, https, dns, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

1) I have a godaddy domain with linux hosting that I use for a landing page, let's say `www.mywebsite.com`

2) I have an azure web app that I configed using a CNAME record and is accessible at `app.mywebsite.com`.

3) I have a wildcard SSL certificate on Azure that is configured with SSL bindings for `app.mywebsite.com`.

this works well and I am able to browse to `app.mywebsite.com` via HTTPS.

Can I use the same certificate to secure my landing page at `www.mywebsite.com`?

Comment: I couldn't understand clearly about what you are asking. Do you mean you want to use azure created  SSL certificate bind with www.mywebsite.com in another azure web app?

Comment: @BrandoZhang no, I want to use azure created SSL to secure a landing page that is hosted outside of azure, on go daddy linux hosting

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the same set of the certificate to secure www.mywebsite.com
If you have installed the certificate on AZURE for app.mywebsite.com then you need to install the same set of certificate on GoDaddy using C-panel (You will require key, server certificate and intermediate bundle certificate to install it on GoDaddy)

Comment: Thanks! I can't seem to figure out how to do this ... where do I get the key and the intermediate certificates?

Comment: @OmriBtian follow the following steps to do so..
1) Login to Azure and open IIS<br>
2) Go to Server Certificates<br>
3) Double-click on the certificate i.e app.mywebsite.com <br>
4) Now you need to click on certificate path tab (here you will see the chaining of certificates, the top one is the root certificate and the middle one is the intermediate certificate)<br>
5) Double-click on the middle one, a new popup will open<br>
6) Now click on details<br>
7) Click on copy to file..

Comment: 8) Click **next** >> select **base-64 encoded x.509 (.cer)**>> click **next**>>save the file as abc
9) Repeat the steps 3) to 7) but you need to select the top one i.e the root certificate and save the file as xyz
10) Open the abc via notepad, copy the content and save the content in a new notepad say 123.txt 
11) Similarly, open the xyz via notepad, copy the content and paste it in 123.txt file below the first content

Comment: In GoDaddy there is **Manage SSL Certificate** there you can paste the whole content of 123.txt in the intermediate CA bundle or upload the file by saving the file from 123.txt to 123.cer/123.crt